# Flutter animation of burning match

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

right now I am giving myself a first dive into Flutter animations. What I need is animation of a match getting burnt. What can I use to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such animations in Flutter Flare. Check out https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter

Create an animation on https://flare.rive.app/ and export using the export engine, or you can find ready resources on https://flare.rive.app/explore/popular/trending/all

once you get the `.flr` file from there, your can import it into your flutter app using the `flare_flutter` plugin.

```
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlareActor("assets/Filip.flr", alignment:Alignment.center, fit:BoxFit.contain, animation:"idle");
  }
}
```